# creating proxy url with meteorjs

Tags: meteor

I was wondering how I might achieve the following using Ironrouter in meteorjs:

```
app.route("/api/tts").get(function(req,res){
  res.type('audio/mpeg');

  var text = req.query.q;
  var request = require('request');
  var url = "https://translate.google.pl/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&q=" + text + "&tl=en&total=1&idx=0&client=t&prev=input";
  request.get(url).pipe(res);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `iron:router` installed already, then you already can. All you need to do is install `request` using `meteorhacks:npm`.

Then you simply write:

```
Router.route("/api/tts", function () {
  // NodeJS request object
  var req = this.request;
  // NodeJS response object
  var res = this.response;
  res.type('audio/mpeg');

  var text = req.query.q;
  var request = Meteor.npmRequire('request');
  var url = "https://translate.google.pl/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&q=" + text + "&tl=en&total=1&idx=0&client=t&prev=input";
  request.get(url).pipe(res);
}, { where: 'server' });
```

Let me know if that works.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use IronRouter, Meteor routing is done on the client 
(the answer from @rclai won't work because the request is still being sent from the client..)

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45957165/1177832) using the `WebApp` module shipped with Meteor to define server routes is exactly what you need.

e.g. something like this:

```
import { WebApp } from 'meteor/webapp';

WebApp.connectHandlers.use('/api/tts', (req, res, next) => {

  var text = res.query.q;
  var url = "https://translate.google.pl/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&q=" + text + "&tl=en&total=1&idx=0&client=t&prev=input";

  HTTP.call("GET", url, {}, function(err, response){

      if(err){
         res.writeHead(500);
         res.end('Failed...');
      }
      else {
         res.end(response.content);
      }
    });

});
```