# intercept data posted in meteorjs using extern api

Tags: reactjs, api, meteor, meteor-react

I am using meteor-react, and I encounter some problems with the external api.
In my project, I use pure meteor as server and react as client.

I want to get some data posted using a url's body (sent from external api).

ex: this an example of the url with the body

```
http:\\api\test
{
  name: test
}
```

I need to get the information in the body.

I really don't know how to implement that in my meteor project, and i don't know from where (whether the server side or client side), I should implement my code.

I have tried these instructions but it is not working:

```
WebApp.connectHandlers.use('/notif',bodyParser.json());
WebApp.connectHandlers.use('/path', bodyParser.urlencoded());
WebApp.connectHandlers.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  API.handleRequest(res, req);
});
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a server-side router. I would recommend https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/picker since it is more light-weight than the default alternative, iron-router.

Add the package to your project:

```
meteor add meteorhacks:picker
```

Add the [`body-parser` npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser):

```
meteor npm install --save body-parser
```

In your server code:

```js
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
Picker.middleware(bodyParser());

Picker.route('/api/test', (params, req, res, next) => {
  console.log("tada!", req.body.name);
  res.end('ok');
});
```

Comment: You can also use `express` if you prefer an npm module, or you might be familiar with it already. It is also lightweight

Comment: That's interesting. How do you use express for server-side routing in Meteor? Something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/45957165/1087119? I guess that works, too.

Comment: Yeah, even without express too, just using the built in webApp, cool!